# How to create a non-persistent user in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically what I'm trying to do is to ask for a temporary guest login that asks for only a nickname and not a password. I'm assuming this never gets saved into the database?

I'm not sure what approach to take into accomplishing this.

Comment: You can use **Cookies**:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: @dkp Thanks, originally I was wondering if sessions would work. I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: @dkp Would you by chance know if Rails stores all valid session cookies so I can validate for uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason something will get saved into the database is if you explicitly call `save` on it.

You can emulate a guest user with something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :guest
  validate :is_not_guest

  def self.guest(*args)
    new(*args).tap { |u| u.guest = true }
  end

  def guest?
    !!@guest
  end

protected
  def is_not_guest
    return unless (guest?)

    self.errors.add(:base, 'Cannot save guest user'
    false
  end
end
```

This should preclude saving a guest, and you can use it like this:

```
@user = User.guest(username: session[:username])
```

Comment: I think I phrased my question poorly. Sorry. What I meant was that there will be no "normal" user authentication. It will just ask for a name and you are in.

Comment: @JadenWang Define your User model with no password requirement or adapt this Guest approach to give you a wrapper around what's present in the session data.

Comment: `cookies.signed` should suffice for my purposes I believe.